# Create Switchable class in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to create a switchable class in java
A one that I can make switch case on it
something like that

```
public class MySwitchableClass implements Comparable<MySwitchableClass>
{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MySwitchableClass arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
    }
}
```

and then I use it like that

```
    MySwitchableClass s = new MySwitchableClass();
    MySwitchableClass s1 = new MySwitchableClass();

    switch(s){
    case s1:
        //do something
        break;
        default break;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want that exactly? What behaviour do you want in `MySwitchableClass`?

Comment: Hmm, try using an enum.

Comment: @RohitJain: OP wants to create a class which can be put as an argument for `switch`

Comment: @justhalf. Yeah I saw that. I'm not asking `what?`, I asked `Why?`.

Comment: `A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer .`

Comment: Probably what OP needs is an enum, or probably he just want to shorten a long conditionals. We don't know for now. haha

Comment: I think I will use enum instead. My point is that I am trying to implement a class that will be used as a configuration parameter type by other programmers and they will need to take a decision based on the value of this parameter. So, I was thinking of making it easy for them to use switch-case instead of multiple if-else lies

Comment: I thought there may be another Interface to implement that can make my class accepted as a parameter to a switch-case statement. I was thinking of inheriting from the Integer class but it is final.

Comment: Don't use a switch statement, use polymorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I didn't know that Java supports this rich enum just like a normal class.

I used an enum and defined all needed fields and methods. I also implemented a desired interface and the enum by default is a switchable type.

So, enum can do everything I need.
My enum definition as follows

```
public enum GearType implements ConfigurationParameter {
    Automatic("Automatic"), Manual("Manual");

    private String type;

    GearType(String _type) {
        type = _type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomeFunction(Object caller) {
        //TODO function code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Not possible. From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) :

> The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: Or `String` from Java 7 onwards

Comment: True. I took a link from Java 5. I updated with the link to the Java 7 JLS. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The `switch` statement does not accept classes, but it does accept enums.  You can create an `enum` type to hold the class types and set them as a field in each class.  The enum type can then be exposed through an interface method, which is utilized in the `switch` statement.

**MyClassType Enum**

```
public enum MyClassType {
    CLASSA, CLASSB
}
```

**Discoverable Interface**

```
public interface Discoverable {
    public MyClassType getType();
}
```

**ClassA**

```
public class ClassA implements Discoverable {

    private MyClassType type = MyClassType.CLASSA;

    public MyClassType getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

**ClassB**

```
public class ClassB implements Discoverable {

    private MyClassType type = MyClassType.CLASSB;


    public MyClassType getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Discoverable a = new ClassA();
    Discoverable b = new ClassB();

    switch (a.getType()) {
    case CLASSA:
        System.out.println("class a");
        break;
    case CLASSB:
        System.out.println("class b");
        break;
    }

}
```

An even better approach would be to put this logic into `ClassA` and `ClassB` and expose it through the interface.

**Interface Changes**

```
public interface Discoverable {
    public void doWork();

}
```

**ClassA Changes**

```
public class ClassA implements Discoverable {

    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("class a");
    }
}
```

**ClassB**

```
public class ClassB implements Discoverable {

    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println("class b");
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Discoverable a = new ClassA();
    Discoverable b = new ClassB();
    a.doWork();    
}
```

Comment: Great workaround. However, I need to switch between different instances of the same class not between different classes

Answer (score 1):

Value for a `switch` statement can only be primitive data types or enums or strings. What your are trying to do cannot be implemented. What you can do instead is call a function on that class which will return a primitive data type.

Comment: Since Java 7 also `String`

Comment: Hmmm, haven't used Java 7 till now. Didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Java switch works with a restricted number of data types, not custom objects.

See explanation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) (applies for Java 7).

You could override the `Object.toString` method in your class and switch with `yourInstance.toString` if you use Java 7.

Using `switch` and implementing `Comparable` are two very different things.

Comment: I don't mean to use Comparable. but I thought there may be another Interface to implement that can make my class accepted as a parameter to a switch-case statement.

Comment: @IslamIbrahim well as I mentioned, if you override the `toString` method into something you can use in a switch (and you employ Java 7, which allows `String` switches) then you can switch `yourInstance.toString". Otherwise you could also override the `hashCode` method and switch with the `int` value.